# Splitting Quad to 1:7,500 in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, esri-geodatabase, features

Here I have 1:24,000k quads. I know how to use the word split toolbox. What I would like to split 24,000K to 1:7,500 or 6,000k. Is there a way around for me to do that ?

For example,, if you have one quad that is 1:24,000 and you want to break it down to either 1:6,000 or 1:7,500 ?

I have about 269 quads and need them to break down to where I want 1:6,000 or 1:7,500.

I am using ArcGIS Desktop 9.3.1.

Comment: Are you basically wanting to quarter them up from one raster to four?

Comment: The results are still going to be 1:24k, just with smaller extents. You'll need more accurate data to achieve 1:7500.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than split the quad, you can just set up a quad layer and a copy of another quad layer with colors 1) Done = blue 2) Brown = needs review 3) Yellow = Not Done.

You can open Layers Overview and put the two quads layer as a group and then display it as a Layer Overview under properties.

Save a lot of my time by just looking at it as I go on track.[image: Here it is what it looks like]

Comment: Where did you find this "Layers Overview" window?  It's not something that I recall having seen in any ArcGIS Desktop version, and it is not mentioned in the ArcGIS 10.4 for Desktop help: http://desktop.arcgis.com/search/?q=%22layers%20overview%22&p=0&language=en&product=arcgis-desktop&version=10.4&n=15&collection=all

Comment: Recall that this is from 2012 and if you go to the menu at the top of ArcMap and click on Windows  scroll down Viewer, I believe ESRI has remove Layer to Viewer.

Comment: So, it has been 3 years since I used it.. I will and try and check if I open it and tried to remember it.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to clip each 24k quad image into smaller 6k or 7.5k sizes. I've never seen an 6k or 7.5k index, hopefully you have that created already. You probably need a script to do this. Here are the command line tools I would use:


ogr2ogr - extract an individual 6k tile from the master 6k tile shapefile.
gdalwarp - clip your 24k image to the 6k tile, specify -cutline. 
gdal_rasterize - if your 6k tile is rotated at all, make the pixels outsize the 6k tile transparent, specify -i for invert, to convert the pixels that do not overlap the tile.